# S1000D Publication Module drops Graphics in PDF

Tags: xml, pdf, graphics

Below is code for a S1000D XML Publication Module (PM) which is used to tie together data modules, stylesheets, schema, and entities into a single publication for PDF output out of Arbortext.  The PM code below only has a single dmref to a single data module that contains 2 graphics. The problem I'm experiencing is perplexing. When I publish a PDF out of Arbortext using the PM code below it generates a PDF that is missing 2 graphics.  However, if I PDF publish the data module XML code directly out of Arbortext without involving the PM code below the PDF prints with the 2 graphics properly displaying. What this tells me is that the PM code below has something wrong that is preventing the 2 graphics from being included in the PDF output.

I would be very grateful if anyone out there who knows something about S1000D / XML Publication Modules can offer some advice on what is wrong with the PM code below. What do I need to do to make the 2 missing graphics properly display in the published PDF using Publication Module XML code?  Any info will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Arbortext, Inc., 1988-2011, v.4002-->
<!DOCTYPE dmodule [
<!ENTITY ICN-LOLA55-DE-A010307-L-04939-00386-A-01-1 SYSTEM "C:\Test\ICN-LOLA55-DE-A010307-L-04939-00386-A-01-1.JPG" NDATA JPEG>
<!ENTITY ICN-LOLA55-DE-A010307-L-04939-00385-A-01-1 SYSTEM "C:\Test\ICN-LOLA55-DE-A010307-L-04939-00385-A-01-1.PNG" NDATA PNG>
<!ENTITY % ISOEntities PUBLIC "ISO 8879-1986//ENTITIES ISO Character Entities 20030531//EN//XML" "http://www.s1000d.org/S1000D_4-0-1/ent/ISOEntities">
%ISOEntities;
<!NOTATION JPEG SYSTEM "JPEG">
<!NOTATION PNG SYSTEM "PNG">
]>
<?Pub Inc?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="file:///C:/test/FO-3031-A00-USARMY-MAIN_001-00_EN-US.xsl" type="text/xsl" media="print,pdf" alternate="yes"?>
<pm xmlns:dc="http://www.purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="c:\ptc\dtds\S1000D_4-0-1\xml_schema_master\pmSchema.xsd">
    <identAndStatusSection>
        <pmAddress>
            <pmIdent>
                <pmCode modelIdentCode="LOLA55" pmIssuer="12340" pmNumber="OPI01" pmVolume="00"/>
                <language countryIsoCode="US" languageIsoCode="en"/>
                <issueInfo inWork="01" issueNumber="000"/>
            </pmIdent>
            <pmAddressItems>
                <issueDate day="09" month="06" year="2009"/>
                <pmTitle>OPERATOR'S MANUAL</pmTitle>
                <shortPmTitle>EQUIPMENT NAME MODEL X (NSN 0000-00-000-0000) (EIC XXX)</shortPmTitle>
            </pmAddressItems>
        </pmAddress>
        <pmStatus issueType="new">
            <security securityClassification="01"/>
            <dataRestrictions>
                <restrictionInstructions>
                    <dataDistribution>DISTRIBUTION STATEMENT A: Approved for public release; distribution
is unlimited.</dataDistribution>
                    <exportControl>
                        <exportRegistrationStmt>
                            <simplePara>WARNING: Export control statement here.</simplePara>
                        </exportRegistrationStmt>
                    </exportControl>
                    <dataDestruction>DESTRUCTION NOTICE: Destroy by any means possible to prevent
disclosure of contents or reconstruction of the document.</dataDestruction>
                </restrictionInstructions>
                <restrictionInfo>
                    <policyStatement>Classification source and reason for classification of this
publication per DODI 5200.001-R.</policyStatement>
                </restrictionInfo>
            </dataRestrictions>
            <responsiblePartnerCompany>
                <enterpriseName>HEADQUARTERS, DEPARTMENT OF THE ARMY</enterpriseName>
            </responsiblePartnerCompany>
            <originator enterpriseCode="07GB6">
                <enterpriseName>BTAS COE</enterpriseName>
            </originator>
            <applic>
                <displayText/>
            </applic>
            <pubMedia pubMediaCode="PDF" pubMediaType="PDF - Optimized for Standard page size"/>
            <qualityAssurance>
                <firstVerification verificationType="tabtop"/>
                <secondVerification verificationType="onobject"/>
            </qualityAssurance>
            <remarks>
                <simplePara>GENERAL NOTICE: General purpose notices may appear here.</simplePara>
            </remarks>
        </pmStatus>
    </identAndStatusSection>
    <content>
        <pmEntry pmEntryType="pmt51">
            <dmRef>
                <dmRefIdent>
                    <dmCode assyCode="07" disassyCode="01" disassyCodeVariant="00" infoCode="042" infoCodeVariant="A" itemLocationCode="O" modelIdentCode="LOLA55" subSubSystemCode="3" subSystemCode="0" systemCode="A01" systemDiffCode="DE" />
                </dmRefIdent>
                <dmRefAddressItems>
                    <dmTitle>
                        <techName>F-WHFD</techName>
                        <infoName>F-WHFD Description</infoName>
                    </dmTitle>
                </dmRefAddressItems>
            </dmRef>
        </pmEntry>
    </content>
</pm>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: try to link to the flat Schema, not the master as master will not be provided for authoring. In this case the Schema is called "pm.xsd"

Second: there is no reason to define the graphic entities as they are not used in the pm itself. How are the entities defined in the data module? Absolute or relative path? Is there an "in-between" FO document available? If yes then check the Definition of the entities in there.